# Socket.io - Authentication on every socket event for Session management

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io, jwt, middleware

How to use an authentication middleware that triggers on each socket event instead of each connection?

I want to use this for session management in a react-node application. I'll send a JWT token once a user logs in and create a new row in my sessions table in my database. But after he logs in, I want to check if he is the same person for every following events by using the mentioned middleware. The front-end client will send the token through cookies.

My sign in and sign out work over socket.io and not over HTTP.

Comment: Once connected, a socket.io connection uniquely belongs to one particular endpoint.  That endpoint can't change while the socket.io connection is connected.  So, it's unclear why or what you think you need to reverify on subsequent messages on the same connection.  How exactly would you check if it was the same person anyway?  All you get with a socket.io is the message itself.  There's no other auth credentials unless the client puts them inside the message in which case you can just write your own function to check the data inside the message.

Comment: Actually there is a socket.io [middleware](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-use-fn) that triggers on every message. Keeping that aside, what you said was correct. I was not fully aware of the concept while asking the question. Thanks for the comment explaining about the re-verification.

Comment: Actually socket.io middleware functions are called for each incoming connection, not each incoming message. They are a great place to do authentication checks. This tracks with what jfriend00 explained about authentication over TCP in general.

https://socket.io/docs/v4/middlewares/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once connected, a socket.io connection uniquely belongs to one particular endpoint. That endpoint can't change while the socket.io connection is connected. So, as with any TCP connection, you would typically authenticate/verify the connection when the socket.io connection first connects and from then on, you would just process incoming messages from that particular client without additional verification.  This is generally how pretty much everything that uses TCP and authentication works.  TCP itself has protections so that a socket can't easily be hijacked by another endpoint mid-connection.

So, it's unclear why or what you think you need to reverify on subsequent messages on the same connection.

With socket.io, what you get on each incoming message is the message itself. There's no other auth credentials unless the client puts them inside the actual message in which case you can just write your own function to check the data inside the message.

If you were putting credentials in every message, you could use `socket.use()` to process every single incoming message and check for whatever you wanted to check for in the message.

Comment: Very helpful tip. tnx